# Why doesn't DataFormatString work in my MVC application?

Tags: razor, linq-to-sql, data-annotations

I have a numeric field that is defined as a decimal. I'm trying to show it as an integer value though.

My model:

```
[Column(CanBeNull = true, DbType = "numeric", Name = "VHCL_ODOMTR")]
  [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:f0}", HtmlEncode = false, NullDisplayText = "")]
  [Display(Name = "Odometer")]
  public decimal? VehicleOdometer { get; set; }
```

My Razor:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.VehicleOdometer)
```

My output is always a text box with ONE decimal.  I cannot make it stop doing this. I've tried {0:D}, {0:#}, and using a capital F instead of lowercase. Even trying "F9" shows 1 decimal and not 9.  Seems to completely ignore the DataFormatProperty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because [DisplayFormatAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displayformatattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is designed to be used with templated view helpers (i.e. `Html.EditorFor` and `Html.DisplayFor`).  So, in order for this to work, you need to use:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.VehicleOdometer)
```

Comment: Thank you. Just when I think I'm getting MVC figured out, I do something like this and realize how much I have left to learn!